# Why FPS is not showing any data in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I was checking [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/) and found [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/sergeche/pen/gwBjqG) about CSS animation:

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #a02615;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: -75px;
  left: -75px;
  animation: sun-spin 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes sun-spin {
 from { transform: rotate(0); }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<img src="//sergeche.github.io/gpu-article-assets/images/sun-full.png" class="sun" />
```

I wanted to check the FPS for this animation. When I open the FPS meter, I can see the FPS is always around 60:

[image: Chrome DevTools FPS meter]

However, when I run a Performance profile in Chrome DevTools, the FPS remains empty:

[image: Performance Profile]

Any idea why I am not seeing the green line at 60 FPS in the DevTools?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Did you manage to get this resolved?

Comment: Hi @Questionnaire, unfortunately, I'm still facing this issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this, you need to switch on Chrome's FPS meter (under the Rendering tab - FPS meter), and **simultaneously** record performance (under Chrome's Performance tab). Unless the FPS meter is running at the time of recording, the FPS values will not show up in the performance recording (having said this, for this particular animation, I have managed to get FPS values to show up even when the FPS meter check box is not selected).

Make sure that you're not running the animation through codepen.io when recording performance. Running the code locally worked for me (refer to screenshot).

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but the FPS is still not showing up, can you add a screenshot to see what you are getting? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Armel I have edited my answer. Hope this works well for you.

Comment: even fps meter is removed from rendering